# Spark web UI unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, ssh, cluster-computing, apache-spark-standalone

i have installed spark2.0.0 on 12 nodes (in cluster standalone mode), when i launch it i get this :

```
./sbin/start-all.sh
```

> starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-ibnb25.out
>
> localhost192.17.0.17: ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost192.17.0.17: Name or service not known
>
> 192.17.0.20: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mbala/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb28.out
>
> 192.17.0.21: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb29.out
>
> 192.17.0.19: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb27.out
>
> 192.17.0.18: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb26.out
>
> 192.17.0.24: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb32.out
>
> 192.17.0.22: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb30.out
>
> 192.17.0.25: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb33.out
>
> 192.17.0.28: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb36.out
>
> 192.17.0.27: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb35.out
>
> 192.17.0.17: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb25.out
>
> 192.17.0.26: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb34.out
>
> 192.17.0.23: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/mName/fer/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-mName-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-ibnb31.out

i have already set the port o master Port=8081 and its IP=192.17.0.17 means the HOSTNAME=ibnb25, i launched the cluster from this host.

from my local machine i use this command to access to the cluster

```
 ssh mName@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

and when i wanted to access to the web UI from my local machine, i used the IPaddress of the master (HOST ibnb25)

```
192.17.0.17:8081
```

but it couldn't be displayed, so i tried with the  address that i use to access to the  cluster

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:8081
```

but nothing is displaying on my browser..... what is wrong?? pleaseeee help me

Answer (score 0):

Your /etc/hosts file seems to be incorrectly set up.

You should get hostname and IP with following commands:

```
hostname
hostname -i
```

Make sure there is space between hostname and IP.

Sample /etc/hosts file looks like :

```
192.17.0.17  <hostname>
192.17.0.17  localhost
<Other IP1>  <other hostname1>
.
.
.
<Other IP-n>  <other hostname-n>
```

Make sure to have all IP host entries in cluster on each node in /etc/hosts file.

For FQDN read [this](https://github.com/DigitalOcean-User-Projects/Articles-and-Tutorials/blob/master/set_hostname_fqdn_on_ubuntu_centos.md).

Comment: do u mean slaves file?

Comment: and is it ok that i use the brower from my local machine?

Comment: check /etc/hosts file. I have mentioned it clearly, did you even run hostname and hostname -i commands? its ok.

Comment: yup i did, hostname gave 'ibnb25' and hostname -i gave '10.0.10.45',

Comment: but when i use ifconfig it gives :  inet adr:192.17.0.17

Comment: may i ask you what is the difference between 'ifconfig' and 'hostname -i' and why they gave 2 different values for the same host

Comment: i used sudo vi /etc/hosts but it seems that i dont have all privelege, this is the error message ""mName is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.""

Comment: 'ifconfig' lists all network adapters and their information including ip addresses, hostname -i gives what is in your /etc/hosts file resolved as per your hostname. though you must have googled that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122209/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-hammad).